# Can SE be considered to a both dangerous and helpful network?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

While I feel that SO or SE helps people especially programmers and sysadmins to get knowledge on things they really need to do or work on I tend to feel the down votes, regulation of questions and answers, harsh words thrown to newbies tend to make it dangerous as you grow from a new contributor especially at the moment.
Don't you think SO should be considered as both dangerous and helpful just like other social sites to help people with questions to ask them without fearing to get whipped with down votes or strong words.

Comment: In what way is this site "dangerous"?

Comment: in the way people are quick to downvote a post and general feeling a newbie gets

Comment: There is no legitimate definition of "dangerous" which can be applied to voting and curation. Maybe you're picking the wrong word.

Comment: I had a legitimmate question here but my friend just costed me my SO account

Comment: Hi, Anisi. [I think you may want to have a look at this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/). I don't know what made you fell "unwelcome", but please know that we are trying to change. It won't be a short process, and probably we will fail a lot along the road. But I hope we will get there someday.

Comment: In the meantime know that generally downvotes aren't intended to be mean spirited - they should be just a way to rank content. Sadly, some people seem to think that they need to bring a question down to at least -100 to rank it properly, but please try to don't make it personal.

Comment: I was going to post a longer answer... but the post was closed before I could, so forgive me if all I could give was a small comment.

Comment: Question legitimacy is a common defense used against downvotes.  We have no trouble believing that you're actually having the problem you're posting about.  What we have trouble with is not meeting our quality standards.  Question legitimacy has no bearing on whether or not our standards are met.

Comment: @Anisi - How did another person cost your Stack Overflow account.  Only you are supposed to have access to your account.  One does not get question banned from a single bad question.  One does not get suspended for asking a single bad question unless there is a clear pattern of low-quality contributions being submitted.  You might want to clarify your question and provide examples of other users throwing harsh words towards you.

Comment: @Ramhound They were reported and caught for sockpuppetry there, so their account was suspended.

Comment: I also read the the question which was linked as a duplicate to this question. The wording of this question may need some changes. But it not clear to me that if these questions are really the same! This question mainly address **psychological effects** of ***all types*** of rejections that one might face for a question! The other question simply asks what could be the **reasons** for question-***down-votes***!

Comment: @Anisi I wish you changed **dangerous** to something like harmful or inhibiting or something more relatable for the situation!

Answer (score 8):

I think you're misinterpreting the whole goal of Stack Exchange. Each site is meant to be a high-quality library of questions and answers. It's not "dangerous". Yes, we do downvote and close questions sometimes, but that's only to keep the quality of the site high.

When in doubt, you can refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask for the relevant site. If you disagree with the closure, you can cast a reopen vote when you have [enough reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) or ask about it on meta.

So, no, Stack Overflow cannot be considered both dangerous and helpful. We only use downvotes for bad questions, and harsh comments can be [flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). But most comments are to help you learn how to use the site, not to make you hate Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have also read the goal. And I think its a tricky phrasing of an statement as it is plausible to assume they also need to reach to new members in order to earn more advertisement-income. And based on the goal I should say it is far better for people to just search the website for answer to a question similar to theirs! Also **personal opinions** said to not matter here! Then judgment of if the questions are similar or not becomes the matter of foreseeing the future and reading the mind of potential readers, to see **their personal opinions**, which is a contradiction on it self!

Comment: All I want to say is: It is obvious that the owner/s of the network want people to ask questions but asking question is also discouraged! And Although some rules have 
 been mentioned. Ultimately the judgment for a question being good or bad in many case is matter of opinions. And opinions are not always depend on logic but also many psychological factors!

Comment: @AKL asking questions isn't discouraged; asking *bad* questions is discouraged. Bad questions tend to get downvoted and/or closed to rank the question below other questions, and also signal to the author that their question wasn't a good one. There certainly are some borderline cases where opinion plays a factor, but for the most part the rules and guidelines play the biggest rule in deciding if a question should be downvoted or not.